# Measure and limit Android app's total web usage?

Tags: android

From what I read, unlimited mobile download plans are disappearing. I think Sprint might have one of the only ones left.

For an Android app that makes frequent Internet downloads, is there any way to measure -- and possibly cap -- the cumulative amount of data downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

You should find an implementation for this:

A very ***simple example***

```
public class DownloadSherif{
private static int MAX_DOWNLOAD_PER_DAY = 999;
private int last_24_hours_downloaded;

public DownloadSherif(){
    //get last_24_hours_downloaded from saved container
}

public boolean canDownload(int download_size){
    if((download_size+last_24_hours_downloaded)<=MAX_DOWNLOAD_PER_DAY)
         return true;
    else
         return false;
}

public void downloaded(int just_downloaded){
     last_24_hours_downloaded += just_downloaded;
}
}
```

Now every time you want to download you must ask permission using `canDownload`

**Final Notes**

- Keep in mind that you must keep track of the `in the last X hours`
- In downloading web content: you can know the content-length of the file using the http HEAD method defined in [RFC 2616 Fielding, et al.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).